# Change MySQL from looking at LocalHost to different IP on local machine

Tags: mysql, windows-7, xampp

Thanks to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108387/apache-and-iis-side-by-side-both-listening-to-port-80-on-windows2003), I was linked [to this article](http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/iis7-post-44-iis7-and-apache-on-the-same-machine), which, after giving [my PC two IPAddresses](http://www.loadtestingtool.com/help/how-setup-ip.shtml), was able to have IIS and Apache living happily on the same PC at the same time.

I also added the following lines in my hosts file so that IIS could run normal w/o interfering with my playtime:

> 192.168.1.99   localapache
>
> 192.168.1.2    localhost  #Required since I added two ip addresses

I want my Apache/PHP/MySql to go to .99 and IIS to use .2.

Now, I'm down to configuring MySql.  According to XAMPP's control panel, it starts/stops when requested (e.g. [image]) .  However, when I try to run mysql.exe, I get the following error message:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   (10061)

The only changes to mysql that I've made is adding the following line to my.ini:

> bind-address="192.168.1.99" #.99 is my Apache address

Is there some other mysql configuration change I need to make so that mysql looks to 192.168.1.99 and not localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

MySQL would only let me connect to it if I removed the entry in my hosts file listed above.  I also removed the *bind-address* configuration in my *my.ini* so that it would bind to to 127.0.0.1.  Basically, I put my box back in the state it would be in by default for connecting to MySql.

From there I ran the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -p
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I understand having no password for root is not recommended.

I also understand the command above allows anyone in the world to connect to mySql.  That's fine. It's a dev machine sitting behind a firewall; no worries there.

So apparently I should have started with the MySQL install first and granted the privileges I wanted before I made IP changes.

I'm sure there's a smarter way, but I now have IIS, SQL Server, Apache and mySql living in harmony on my machine; which is exactly what I wanted.

No need for virtual machines.